# Forming triangles from 4n points on a square

Tags: self-study, combinatorics

Suppose that n points are given at any side of a square. None of these points coincides with a vertex of the square. How many triangles are determined by these 4n points?

The answer given is like so: "The number of triangles whose vertices belong to three different sides of the square is $4(n − 1)^3$. The number of triangles with two vertices on the same side of the square is $4{n − 1 \choose  2}(3n − 3)$."

This answer makes sense. For the first, you choose the one side to exclude (in 4 ways) and then pick one point from each of the three sides. For the second, you choose the side with two vertices (in 4 ways), pick 2 points from that side, and then pick any one point from the three remaining sides.

...except why is it $n-1$ and not $n$? There are $n$ points to each side, after all. For the case of all points being on different sides, there should be $4.n.n.n = 4n^3$ ways to choose, by my calculations. Similarly, the second case should be $4{n\choose  2}(3n)$.

The textbook answer also doesn't make sense in the light of the cases n=1 and n=2.

Have I made a mistake in reading or understanding something crucial, or is this mistake on the textbook?

Comment: This problem is probably better addressed on https://math.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: This question has been asked there: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1372944/total-number-of-triangles-that-can-be-made-by-4n-points-n-at-each-side-of-s?rq=1

Comment: Interesting, thank you! The answer there is more elegant than this formulation, indeed, and it too uses n rather than n-1. The resulting expression when simplified matches my answer, too. I think it's fair to write this off as a textbook error.